# hittin UIImageViews with another UIImageView

Tags: ios, xcode

I have 10 UIImageViews on the screen.  They are all in an array called posArray.  I also have another UIImageView that is dragged by user and can hit those other 10.  What is the easies way of displaying a simple NSlog message if the one object hits any of the other 10?

Right now i'm using touchesBegin, touchesMoved to move my one object and this array below to test if the one objects hits any of the other ten.

I'm just thinking that there is an easier, less memory spending way, way of doing this for some reason.

```
for (int i = 0; i < [posArray count]; i++) {

    UIImageView *tempPos;
    tempPos = [posArray objectAtIndex:i];

    if (CGRectIntersectsRect(red1.frame, tempPos.frame)) {

        red1.center = CGPointMake(tempPos.center.x, tempPos.center.y);
        NSLog(@"position piece touched");
    }

}
```

Comment: both sides of the OR in your if condition are the same?

Comment: that second one shouldn't be there.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can also use fast enumeration to get some more speed. Also you can add a break statement after you found one match (if you just need one match):

```
for (UIImageView * tempPos in posArray){
   if (CGRectIntersectsRect(red1.frame, tempPos.frame)) {
      red1.center = CGPointMake(tempPos.center.x, tempPos.center.y);
      NSLog(@"position piece touched");
      break;
   }
}
```